# Unable to resume application after receiving push notification in android

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, google-cloud-messaging, resume

I am developing an android application in titanium, in which I included google cloud messaging. I am able to get registration id from server. Also when my application is running I am able to receive the message from my server. But When my application is running in background At that time my application is able to receive message.But when I clicked on notification it does not resume my application. I added the following code in my app.js:

```
var intent = Titanium.Android.createIntent({
    action: Titanium.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
    className: 'com.nrcomps.rtlireportsandroid.RtlIreportsAndroidActivity',
    packageName: 'com.nrcomps.rtlireportsandroid',     
   flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | 
   Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK     
});
intent.addCategory(Titanium.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
var pending = Ti.Android.createPendingIntent({
     activity : Ti.Android.currentActivity,
     intent : intent,
     type : Ti.Android.PENDING_INTENT_FOR_ACTIVITY,
     flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @Sonal, please dont add signatures in your posts. Instead update your name in your profile. Stack overflow has a very beautifull signatures of yours, here in the blue rectangle in the bottom right corner of your every post.

Comment: i wont have idea on titanium .. plz try by removing  flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | 
   Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ---------------and-------ype : Ti.Android.PENDING_INTENT_FOR_ACTIVITY,
     flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: I have removed the all flags. but still it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Intent` flags on the `Intent`. You were specifying them in the call to get a `PendingIntent`.

```
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
    notificationIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks to quick reply. I have added the code which you provided, but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
String st = "message";
        NotificationManager notifymanManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        int s = R.drawable.icon;

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification nt = new Notification(s, st, when);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Woobme.class);
        intent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            nt.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        PendingIntent pd = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);
        nt.setLatestEventInfo(context, st, st, pd);
        int i = 1;
        int hello_id = i;
        long m[] = { 0, 100, 200, 200 };
        nt.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        nt.vibrate = m;

        notifymanManager.notify(hello_id, nt);
```

Comment: intent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); these lines relaunch the old activity its working fine for me... can you post ur code ?

Comment: I am still facing the same problem. I am developing this application in titanium and using java application to send notification. It sends message successfully but when application is in background,It does not launch application. If it is in foreground,it works properly. If I send notification using my titanium app then it launches app properly. Is there any problem to send notification through different application(that is in java)? any help will be appreciated.thanks